# VirtualBox hogs CPU after host wake, fans roar

Tags: debian, windows, virtualbox, cpu-usage, sleep

Run overnight crashes Windows, sleep overnight cranks VirtualBox %CPU on wake.
Either way I must reboot every morning instead of once or twice a year.

Windows 11 Home 22H2 Virtual Box 7.0.4-r154605 running Debian 11.6
"bullseye" guest eventually gets cranky, fans roar until guest reboot.
Guest onscreen: fans too loud, Task Manager shows host VBox CPU 30%, top shows guest Xorg CPU 12%.
Guest offscreen: no fan noise, Task Manager shows host VBox CPU 13%, top shows guest Xorg CPU 61%.
(VMSVGA & VBoxSVGA both need SetVideoModeHint 1920 1080 32 after guest boot)
Doubt wake from sleep makes VBox Graphics Controller spam Xorg as trouble persists after quitting xinit.

Hardware is Samsung Galaxy Book2 Pro 360 with 1920x1080 OLED
(**AVOID** over priced, under cooled, fragile but Samsung claims abuse
and won't fix, touch screen mis-mapped in VirtualBox, 22H2 update broke
fingerprint reader which Samsung & Microsoft acknowledge and say they
won't fix, ...)

Trying various avenues to diagnose and fix:
(best) Somehow configure Windows to not crash overnight - no luck so far.
(tolerable) Somehow configure VirtualBox to not crank CPU - no luck so far.
(worst) close out and shut down guest, sleep host every night, reboot guest every morning - elaborate rituals I suffer now.
Have yet to try making Debian bootable and running Windows in VirtualBox - substantial down time to implement, drivers (LOL, poor support anyway) likely unavailable.

How to silence those fans?

Comment: You could limit maximum CPU frequency.

Comment: Better yet, power down and catch a wave, cowabungaa!

Comment: In a perfect world of dedicated, competent, unharried programmers and bug-free device drivers, *sleep* would work - the real world lacks any sort of *power coma* where nothing needs re-init on wake.  Meanwhile, I tolerate MS-W11 crashes and scan the logs for clues.

Comment: You could install Windows back and enjoy your life. There's no Linux OS and your expectations are way too high. I'm writing this under Fedora 37.